# How to draw a triangle in a 2D array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, shapes

For a class project we need to be able to draw a triangle in a 2D array of chars. Algorithmically I can't work out how to do it.

My current code is this (but it does not work):

```
public void fill() {
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            double x=h;
            while(x<=0){
                drawing.setPoint(i, x, myChar);
                x=Math.ceil(x/2);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want the output to look something like this:

```
....*....
...***...
..*****..
.*******.
*********
```

We can't use any pre-existing methods or classes that relate to drawing.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: @bradimus I updated it

Comment: Unless h <= 0, you'll never enter the while loop, and if it is you won't enter the for loop either.

Comment: Also, x=Math.ceil(x/2) will never reduce to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your drawing, you need 9 columns for 5 rows. So,

```
int height = 5;
int width = 2*height - 1;
```

Even though I'm not sure what `drawing.setPoint(i, x, myChar);` does, I think this example will get you going. I will build a `String` based on `char`s.

```
char fill = '*';
char blank = '.';
```

I'll start the rows at 0 but the columns at 1 to make the math a little clearer.

For `row = 0`, `....*....`  you need one star in `column = 5`.

For `row = 1`, `...***...` you need three stars in `column = 4,5,6`.

For `row = 3`, `.*******.` you need seven stars in `column = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8`.

Notice that for `row i` you need a star in `column j` if the distance between the `height = 5` and the `column j` is less than or equal to `i`. That is, when `| height - column | <= row`

```
for (int row = 0; row < height; row ++) {
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder(width);
    for (int column = 1; column <= width; column ++) {
        char out = Math.abs(column - height) <= row ? fill : blank;
        line.append(out);
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

This yields

```
....*....
...***...
..*****..
.*******.
*********
```

I assume you can use `Math.abs` since your example has `Math.ceil`. If not, you can convert `Math.abs` to an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to tackle this, and you've already seen one answer which draws the picture row-by-row.

I'm going to assume that you've already got routines to create `char[][]` and to print the characters in that array of arrays to the screen. It looks as if you already have a `setPoint()` method too, to poke a point into the structure.

As a beginner, I don't think it helps you to be given a solution. You need to be pointed in the right direction to solve it yourself.

Lots of experienced coders now use Test Driven Design, and you could learn from this: start with a simple case, create a test for that, make that test pass, repeat with more tests until there are no more tests to write.

Eventually you should learn a test framework like jUnit, but for now you can "test" by just running your program. So the first test is, does it work for `height == 1`?

You can pass this test (for now that means, run the program and see that the output looks right) with:

```
   public void drawTriangle(int height) {
        drawing.setPoint(0,5,'*')
   }
```

Job done.

Now to make it work for `height==2`:

```
   public void drawTriangle(int height) {
      drawing.setPoint(0,5,'*');
      if(height == 2) {
         drawing.setPoint(1,4,'*');
         drawing.setPoint(1,5,'*');
         drawing.setPoint(1,6,'*');
      }
   }
```

This still works for `height == 1`, but also works for `height == 2`.

But you can immediately see an opportunity for a loop to replace those three commands for the second row. So:

```
   public void drawTriangle(int height) {
      drawing.setPoint(0,5,'*');
      if(height == 2) {
         for(int 4; i<7; i++) {
            drawing.setPoint(1,i,'*');
         }
      }
   }
```

... and you can pull that out into a method:

```
   public void drawTriangle(int height) {
      drawing.setPoint(0,5,'*');
      if(height == 2) {
          drawRow2();
      }
   }

   private void drawRow2() {
      for(int 4; i<7; i++) {
         drawing.setPoint(1,i,'*');
      }
   }
```

This is called *refactoring* -- writing something that works, but isn't written the best way, testing it to ensure it works, then changing the way it's written one step at a time, so it still works, but in a tidier way.

Hopefully you can see where this is going. You can modify `drawRow2()` to be more general -- `drawRow(int rowNumber)`, and gradually replace the literal numbers in there with variables derived from `rowNumber`. Then you can use `drawRow(0)` to draw the first row, and `drawRow(1)` to draw the second. Then you can draw a three row triangle by adding `drawRow(2)`, and then you can improve that by using a loop instead.